# Analytic bump function and clarification on the identity theorem

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis

I have a basic question about a particular use of the identity theorem.

By *bump function*, I mean a smooth function $f:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ which is $1$ in a $U$ neighborhood of the origin and $0$ outside a larger neighborhood $V$.

I've seen the argument that, because of the identity theorem, there are no analytic bump functions. However, the identity theorem is, as far as I know, only for functions defined in open subsets of $\mathbb{C}$, and neither $U$ nor $V$ are subsets of $\mathbb{C}$. So how can we use the identity theorem here?

Comment: A real analytic function on $\mathbb R^n$ that equals $1$ on a neighborhood of the origin is identically $1.$

Comment: Yes. The question is why

Comment: Apply the identity theorem to $f(z) - 1$.

Comment: Do you know it when $n=1?$

Comment: @zhw. No: I have the same problem, since $U,V$ are not open sets of $\mathbb{C}$ in that case either

Comment: Whatever proof you know for complex analytic functions will work for real analytic functions on $\mathbb R.$ Try it!

Comment: Ok, I will! So it is NOT a consequence of the identity theorem as it is, I guess.

Comment: @zhw. Ok, I will! So it is NOT a consequence of the identity theorem as it is, I guess.

Comment: It actually is. If you have a real analytic function on $\mathbb R,$ it extends to a complex analytic function on some $U \supset \mathbb R,$ where $U$ is open in $\mathbb C.$

Comment: Examine the proof of the identity theorem, and you will realize the only hypothesis that is necessary is that the function is analytic.